# The sound of thunder's like a whip

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme

> The sound of thunder's like a whip,
>   one takes a stab and makes a quip;
>   uncaps a bottle, lights a pipe,
>   accessing files of private type;
>   a mental crisis, break of dawn,
>   can experts solve what's going on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about a

> crack

The sound of thunder's like a whip,

> crack of thunder, crack a whip

one takes a stab and makes a quip;

> give it a crack, crack a joke

uncaps a bottle, lights a pipe,

> crack open, crack pipe

accessing files of private type;

> crack a password

a mental crisis, break of dawn,

> cracking up, crack of dawn

can experts solve what's going on

> a crack team

Comment: I might remove "up" from the mental crisis suggestion since your construct is usually more aligned with laughing.

Comment: Also there is a use of this directly related to a whip, and "take a stab" (make an attempt) can also be described as "take a..."

Comment: @IanMacDonald The usage suggested here is common at least in British English.

Comment: @DJClayworth Not only British.  Just ask Green Day.  Or am I just paranoid?